# NLTK his & hers are tagged differently,

Tags: nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I just started experimenting with Natural Language Processing. My first few lines of code with NLTK gave confusing results.

```
import nltk
exampleArray = ['The book is hers',
               'The book is his']
for item in exampleArray:
    tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(item)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    print(tagged)
```

Output:

```
[('The', 'DT'), ('book', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('hers', 'NNS')]
[('The', 'DT'), ('book', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('his', 'PRP$')]
```

Why are "his" and "hers" tagged so differently?

Comment: I knew from reading that gender bias was a problem in word embeddings and other deep NLP constructs. I did not, however, expect to encounter the problem so soon and so blatantly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation about the model, but the tagger was probably trained on Wall Street Journal text from the Penn Treebank, which is not known for its gender balance.

Note that "his" has the wrong tag, here, too. Both should be PRP. The WSJ treebank has one occurrence of his/PRP (vs. >2000 of his/PRP$, some of which may be errors) and one of Hers/JJ (a tagging error, as far as I can tell). A tagger with a slightly better model (using better training data) should be able to tag "hers" correctly, but "his" is going to remain tricky.

Also, "hers" is tagged often enough as JJ in the Brown and Switchboard subcorpora that I'm not entirely sure what's going on, although my best guess is that they are errors. The [standard PTB tagging guidelines](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC99T42/tagguid1.pdf) clearly says it should be PRP and a quick search doesn't turn up any alternate guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for this well researched answer and useful link. Do you know of other taggers that do better on pronouns. Specifically, I need a tagger that distinguishes between PRP used as subject (he) and PRP used as object (him) in a sentence.

Comment: Hmm, I think the CLAWS7 tagset includes this distinction, but CLAWS5 and the  PTB tagset don't distinguish subjective and objective pronouns, and I don't know of any off-the-shelf CLAWS7 taggers. In general, in order to distinguish subj/obj/iobj you'd need to use a parser rather than just a tagger. For a fairly simple starting point, look at dependency parses with spacy: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy (When I tried it spacy tagged "his" incorrectly in your example as PRP$, but gets "hers" right.)